# Implementing Monoid[Option[A]] Compile-time Error

Tags: scala

When trying to implement the `optionMonoid[A]` from [FP in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), I wrote:

```
def optionMonoid[A] = new Monoid[Option[A]] {
    def op(a1: Option[A], a2: Option[A]) = (a1, a2) match {
        case (Some(x), Some(y)) => Some(x + y)
        case _ => None
    }
    val zero = None
}
```

Why is the compile-time error expecting a String here?

```
C:\Users\Kevin\Workspace\side-work\Monoid>scalac MonoidTesting.scala
MonoidTesting.scala:43: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: String
                        case (Some(x), Some(y)) => Some(x + y)
                                                        ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to pass a `Monoid` instance for `A` so you can `op` the two values in the `Some(x), Some(y)` case. From memory, this is usually done with an implicit arg:

```
def optionMonoid[A](implicit aMonoid:Monoid[A]) = ...

    case (Some(x),Some(y)) => Some(aMonoid.op(x,y))
```

You'll need to fix your `zero` definition too, as it currently won't satisfy the `Monoid` identity law, ie, `op(x, zero) === x === op(zero, x)`. I think this is a useful exercise to work out, so I'll omit the implementation for now.

Comment: What does the `(implicit ...)` do?

Comment: It means if you already have an `implicit` instance of `Monoid[A]` in scope, you can omit the argument to the `optionMonoid` call. Eg, `implicit val monoidForA: Monoid[A] = ...; val monoidForOptionA: Monoid[Option[A]] = optionMoinoid;`. More commonly, you'd already have a pre-defined `implicit Monad[A]` somewhere that you would then import to bring into scope.

Comment: Aside, I'm not familiar with the FP In Scala book, but I would assume the general type class "pattern" would be covered there. This tutorial might also be of use: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/

Comment: Thanks, @Kristian. Conceptually, what does the Option[Monoid].op do? I'm having a hard time reasoning about it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the context is, nor do I think the comments section is the best forum to discuss. I suggest posing your query as a new question (with the appropriate context). If you are on IRC, you should also be able to find help in #scalaz on freenode, where, among others, the authors of FP In Scala sometimes hang out.